# Double Click Event

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, event-handling, silverlight-2.0

How to make a double click event in C# for using Silverlight3.0.
In my project, i had created stackpanel dynamically, When the user double click on the stackpanel, the child window will be displayed. There is no such event in silverlight. How to make a double click event for my application?

Answer (score 0):

Well if look at [this post](http://hackingsilverlight.blogspot.com/2008/02/silverlight-20-double-click-support.html), the author counted the ticks between clicks to be able to simulate a double click in Silverlight. Maybe it will help you.

Comment: also see this blog post: http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2009/01/15/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-82-how-to-implement-double-click.aspx